# NestJS: Set type of @Body()

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

Given the following:

```
@Post()
public async createPet(@Body() petDetails: PostPetDto): Promise<any> {
}
```

By default the type of `@Bod() petDetails` is not the declared type of `PostPetDto` but plain/any. What is the NestJS idiomatic way to have it marshaled to the type?

The type contains methods (eg validate) that should be run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

@Post()
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
public async createPet(@Body() petDetails: PostPetDto): Promise<any> {
}
```

or for set it up as a global-scoped

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

look it https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

Answer (score 1):

The ValidationPipe doesn't automatically transform your payloads to the corresponding DTO classes. To turn this on:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```